# Update a database using a discord bot. Why the bot dont recognize and update the database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, updates, discord

I am developing a discord BOT, where the main function of it is to display the information of the Wiki directly to the players present in the discord. In order for the community to help develop the game, a system was developed in which we were able to add information for the BOT to collect, and then update that information.

In order for this database to be updated, we use pastebin as a data acquisition platform. But there comes the problem the bot is not capturing the information and so little updating the same. Here is the code to do this:

````
import discord
import json
import re
import os
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class WikiCommands:
    def __init__(self, listen_channel_id):
        self.BASE_URL = 'http://bloodstonewiki.pl/index.php/'

        # ID kanału z którego zbieramy pastebiny
        self.channel_id = listen_channel_id

        # Pastebiny zapisujemy tutaj
        self.drop_files_dir = os.path.join('data', 'drop_files')

        # loot.json
        self.loot_json = os.path.join('data', 'loot.json')

        # monster_info.json
        self.monster_info_json = os.path.join('data', 'monster_info.json')

        # wczytanie info o potworach
        self._load_monster_data()

    def get_monster_info(self, message_content):
        monster_name = message_content.replace('!monster', '')
        if not monster_name or len(monster_name) <= 1:
            return "Nieprawidłowe użycie komendy.\nPodaj nazwę potwora, np.```!monster Rabbit```"

        if monster_name[0] == ' ':
            monster_name = monster_name[1:]

        monster_loot = self.get_monster_loot(monster_name.lower())
        if 'org_monster_name' in monster_loot:
            embed_monster_name = monster_loot['org_monster_name']
        else:
            embed_monster_name = monster_name

        if monster_name not in self.monster_info_list:
            monster_info = self._wiki_monster_info(embed_monster_name)
            if monster_info:
                self.monster_info_list[monster_name] = monster_info
        else:
            monster_info = self.monster_info_list[monster_name]

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=embed_monster_name,
            url=self.BASE_URL + embed_monster_name.replace(' ', '_'),
            color=4446036,
        )

        embed.set_author(
            name='Bloodstone Wiki', url=self.BASE_URL,
            icon_url='http://bloodstonewiki.pl/resources/assets/wikiblood2.png?5dda8'
        )

        if 'gif' in monster_info:
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url=monster_info['gif']
            )

        if 'EXP' in monster_info:
            embed.add_field(
                name='Info',
                value='\n**EXP**: {}\n**HP**: {}'.format(
                    monster_info['EXP'],
                    monster_info['HP']
                ),
                inline=True
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name='Zachowanie',
                value='\n**Zwarcie**: {}\n**Dystans**: {}\n**Specjalne**: {}'.format(
                    monster_info['Zwarcie'],
                    monster_info['Dystans'],
                    monster_info['Specjalne']
                ),
                inline=True
            )

        embed.add_field(name='Loot', value=monster_loot['human_readable_str'])
        return embed

    def _wiki_monster_info(self, monster_name):
        result = {}

        r = get(self.BASE_URL + monster_name.replace(' ', '_'))
        # Problemy z wiki
        if r.status_code != 200:
            return result

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        main_content = soup.find(id="mw-content-text")

        # Brak zawartości
        if 'noarticletext' in main_content.div['class']:
            return result

        if main_content.img:
            result['gif'] = 'http://bloodstonewiki.pl' + main_content.img['src']

        tbody = main_content.table.find('tbody')
        for row in tbody.find_all('tr'):
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            if cells and len(cells) == 6:
                result.update({
                    'monster_name': soup.h1.find(text=True).replace('\n', '') or monster_name,
                    'EXP': cells[0].find(text=True).replace('\n', ''),
                    'HP': cells[1].find(text=True).replace('\n', ''),
                    'Zwarcie': cells[2].find(text=True).replace('\n', ''),
                    'Dystans': cells[3].find(text=True).replace('\n', ''),
                    'Specjalne': cells[4].find(text=True).replace('\n', ''),
                })

        return result

    def get_monster_loot(self, monster_name):
        if not monster_name in self.drop_list:
            return {
                'human_readable_str': '`Brak informacji`',
            }

        desc = self.drop_list[monster_name]

        readable = []
        for itm_name, dropped_desc in desc['drop'].items():
            if dropped_desc['min'] >= 1 and (dropped_desc['min'] == dropped_desc['max']):
                count = dropped_desc['min']
            else:
                count = "{}-{}".format(dropped_desc['min'], dropped_desc['max'])

            readable.append(
                "\n`{} {} (szansa: {}, średnio: {})`".format(
                    count,
                    itm_name,
                    str((dropped_desc['times_droped'] / desc['killed']) * 100)[:4] + '%',
                    str(dropped_desc['total'] / desc['killed'])[:4],
                )
            )
        readable = ''.join(readable)
        if readable[-2:] == ', ':
            readable = readable[:-2]

        return {
            'human_readable_str': "\nZabitych: **{}**\n{}".format(
                desc['killed'],
                readable or '`Brak loota`'
            ),
            'org_monster_name': desc['org_name']
        }

    def add_to_loot(self, message_content):
        # Get link from message conent
        regex = r"(https|http)://pastebin.com/(raw/)?([A-Za-z0-9]{8})"
        match = re.findall(regex, message_content)
        if not match:
            raise Exception("InvalidLink")

        # Download files
        for link in match:
            id = link[2]
            fname = os.path.join(self.drop_files_dir, '{}.txt'.format(id))

            if os.path.isfile(fname):
                continue

            with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
                # get request
                response = get('https://pastebin.com/raw/{}'.format(id))
                # write to file
                f.write(response.content)

            self.parse_loot_file(fname)

        # Update loot.json
        self._update_loot_json()

    def parse_loot_file(self, fname):
        regex = r"[\d]{1,2}:[\d]{1,2} : (.+):(.+)"
        with open(fname, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if line[-1] == '.':
                    # You received... ignore this shit
                    continue

                match = re.findall(regex, line)
                if not match:
                    continue

                monster_name_org = match[0][0]
                monster_name = monster_name_org.lower()
                if monster_name not in self.drop_list:
                    self.drop_list[monster_name] = {
                        'org_name': monster_name_org,
                        'killed': 1,
                        'drop': {},
                        'no_drop': False,
                    }
                else:
                    self.drop_list[monster_name]['killed'] += 1

                monster_drop = match[0][1]
                if not monster_drop or len(monster_drop) <= 1:
                    self.drop_list[monster_name]['no_drop'] = True
                    continue

                monster_drop = monster_drop.split(',')
                for item_dropped in monster_drop:
                    if item_dropped[0] == ' ':
                        item_dropped = item_dropped[1:]

                    drop_re = r"([\d]{1,}) (.+)"
                    match = re.findall(drop_re, item_dropped)

                    count = 1
                    if match:
                        count = int(match[0][0])
                        item_dropped = match[0][1]

                    if item_dropped not in self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop']:
                        self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped] = {
                            'min': count,
                            'max': count,
                            'times_droped': 1,
                            'total': count,
                        }
                    else:
                        for item in self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'].keys():
                            if item not in item_dropped:
                                self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped]['min'] = 0

                        self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped]['times_droped'] += 1
                        self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped]['total'] += count
                        if self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped]['min'] > count:
                            self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped]['min'] = count

                        if self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped]['max'] < count:
                            self.drop_list[monster_name]['drop'][item_dropped]['max'] = count

            for monster_name, desc in self.drop_list.items():
                if desc['no_drop']:
                    for _, dropped in desc['drop'].items():
                        dropped['min'] = 0

    def _update_loot_json(self):
        # Save in loot.json
        with open(self.loot_json, 'w+') as f_json:
            json.dump(self.drop_list, f_json)

    def _update_monster_info_json(self):
        # Save in monster_info.json
        with open(self.monster_info_json, 'w+') as f_json:
            json.dump(self.monster_info_list, f_json)

    def _load_monster_data(self):
        # Reload drop list from file
        try:
            with open(self.loot_json) as f_json:
                self.drop_list = json.load(f_json)

            # Remove
            for m, d in self.drop_list.items():
                if m.islower():
                    continue

                d['org_name'] = m
                self.drop_list[m.lower()] = d
                self.drop_list.pop(m, None)

            self._update_loot_json()
        except Exception:
            self.drop_list = {}

        # Reload monster info from file
        try:
            with open(self.monster_info_json) as f_json:
                self.monster_info_list = json.load(f_json)
        except Exception:
            self.monster_info_list = {}
````

I have already refaced and tried to make this link but unfortunately I could not, and I hope your support, any doubts or suggestions will be available.

https://repl.it/@LimaJamal/Heliotrope

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  Are you seeing any error messages in the log?

Comment: i dont have any error in the log. But when i try to put pastebin link, the bot dont acquire data from him. Im show a example:

First example works fine:
https://imgur.com/qjXJ9CW

Second example works fine too, when im wrote a link wrong:
https://imgur.com/qvwDkLh

Third example dont work, and i dont know why, because when i put the link correct, the file is being recognize and update the list of loot:
https://imgur.com/KBs6KOY

Comment: The error occurs in this line bellow: 

def add_to_loot(self, message_content):

Comment: you can open my project in this link too https://repl.it/@LimaJamal/Heliotrope